# Unity Android Build Errors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

After a ton of re-installs and other changes, I'm down to 2 errors. Both errors will appear when I open Unity as well as make an Android build. Despite these errors popping up, it looked as though the build worked (game had strange issues and ran slowly but I don't think that's related).

**1. Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.**

```
Failed to run 'F:\Projects\CompanyName\GameName\Game\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat -b "F:\Projects\MAWGames\Gnome Invaders\Game\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" --no-daemon "-PANDROID_HOME=F:/Programs/AndroidSDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=F:\Projects\MAWGames\Gnome Invaders\Game\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+;com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+;com.android.support:customtabs:+;com.android.support:support-v4:+"'

* Where:
Build file 'F:\Projects\CompanyName\GameName\Game\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle' line: 127

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'PlayServicesResolverGradle'.
> For input string: "0-alpha1"

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

**2. Unable to find Android SDK manager tool**

```
The following Required Android packages cannot be installed:
* extras;google;m2repository 
* extras;android;m2repository 

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.<InstallAndroidSdkPackagesAndResolve>c__AnonStorey19:<>m__27(IAndroidSdkManager)
GooglePlayServices.<Create>c__AnonStoreyA:<>m__D(Boolean)
GooglePlayServices.<InstallPackages>c__AnonStorey5:<>m__5(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<DisplayInstallLicenseDialog>c__AnonStorey6:<>m__6(Result)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:Update(CommandLineDialog)
GooglePlayServices.CommandLineDialog:Update()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

I see a GooglePlayServices theme between the 2 errors. I had installed that package via the command line use of the sdkmanager, but I uninstalled it and it doesn't seem to matter. There's a resolver already added to the project (I believe because of the use of OneSignal), perhaps I need the latest?

Here's a quick shot of the packages I have installed, the tools version they want me to update, and the pop-up dialog that comes from Unity (pasted in there).

[Installed Android Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95s81.jpg)

I'd prefer to update the tools via Unity because when I try to copy the SDKManager tools to another directory (so that I can actually update them since otherwise access would be denied since it's in that folder being updated) and set the --sdk_root, nothing happens. The root doesn't get set, the command seems to be ignored! If I can get Unity to do that for me, that's fantastic.

Anyway, I appreciate the help with this, all of the hoops have almost been jumped through.

Thanks!
-Matt

Comment: The first line of your gradle error `"-PANDROID_HOME=F:/Programs/AndroidSDK"` is using forward slash on a Windows system when everything else is using back slash. Double check your environment variables.

Comment: Good observation! But unfortunately that didn't fix the issue. That was set by Unity via their browse functionality, but I manually changed them to backslashes and get the same error.